# Adding CaviumProvider as Provider, received error

Tags: java, amazon-cloudhsm

I have added cavium as Provider, but it gives error of "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" at runtime.
Any clue or idea would be great help. Jar is already added to build path and included in Maven also.

What have tried is to add jar to build path.

Security.addProvider(new com.cavium.provider.CaviumProvider()); givees error as : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.cavium.provider.CaviumProvider

Comment: Hello there, did you know how to fix this?

Comment: I added the jar in tomacat and It worked.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What Jar? Where?